# Android: Fix orientation based on the position of the device

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I was wondering if it is possible to fix the orientation of a layout based on the position of a device. For example if an app is launched while in a portrait position, the app is fixed in portrait. If the app is launched in landscape the orientation is fixed to landscape.

I understand you can fix the orientation to either portrait or landscape in the manifest but is there a way to fix the orientation dynamically based on the the device position?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the manifest. I haven't tested it but I think that tells Android not to handle those changes. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid not, if I launch the app in portrait and rotate the screen,  it orientates and recreates the activity

Comment: take a look here [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) This should be able to explain it better. Here are two other good links for sensors and configs if you haven't read them. There is a android:ConfigChanges:'noSensor' but I think that will use your devices default landscape
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)